# How do I become a better pilot?

Tags: battlefield-3

I am a beginner Battlefield 3 player and I am having a lot of trouble flying aircraft.  What are some of the things I need to look out for as a pilot?  What are some common strategies to use?

Comment: Are there any specific things you're having trouble with?

Comment: This question is pretty salvageable.

Comment: If you happen to be playing on PC, try out different configurations for controls, there are a number of viable options: keyboard+mouse, just keyboard, or plug in a usb controller.

Answer (score 11):

There a lots on tutorials on [**Youtube**](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=battlefield%203%20jet%20tutorial&oq=battlefield%203%20jet%20tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g7&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=59l2770l0l3006l18l8l0l0l0l0l731l731l6-1l1l0) that are really helpful. Remember Google is also your friend and searching "Battlfield 3 jet tips" is usually is pretty fruitful. I also found [**this**](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Battlefield/MusterBuster-s-Pro-Tips-for-Pilots/td-p/13952953) which is quite detailed and is more theory and good practice so isn't platform specific (since you didn't say what you're playing it on).

My personal advice is basically to just keep practicing. Sure you will have a lot of crashes, unluckly misses and lots of deaths but you will *eventually* get the hang of it if you stick at it.

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

Like you, I was having trouble piloting when I first started. But I did some digging, and found a pretty useful video on [YouTube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJ9neR-BaqM)

It takes a lot of practice, but once you get the hang of it, it's one of the most fun things to do in the game.

Comment: I've got a lot better now and have nearly unlocked everything for the jet I was struggling earlier but I'm fine now got so much better with the gun practised a lot